# The best resolution for Book scanning?

Tags: dpi

I am starting a library. I will be scanning the books. What dpi do i need to make the best records for the future and the archivest who be looking in years to come?

Comment: That's a big question really. Perhaps some more context would help narrow it down. Basically the higher resolution, the better (up to some limit). So if you could scan every page uncompressed at 600-1200 PPI (notice that *PPI* is the right term to use here - not *DPI*) on a calibrated scanner, every page could potentially be used to print a poster. But it will be extremely time consuming and take up lots of disk space. Another extreme would be to focus on scanning at the lowest possible resolution where you can still read the text. Maybe even in 1-bit, like many books you find online.

Comment: Disk space had not been considered, but is cheap enough and  since i am retired, time is not important, realisticly. I want to make pics that are very high quality.  These are rare books. So whw

Comment: Are you trying to preserve the books as a series of high resolution images, or just as text? Either way, half the problem with scanning books is getting the pages flat without breaking the spine. Photography can get a flatter image, using a longer lens from a distance.

Comment: A4 page saved as 600 PPI full of 11pt text as image (=still looking acceptably sharp, if reprinted) can be as small as 0,9 megabytes if saved as PNG (=no quality degrading compression) if it's scanned so that the text is black, has perfectly faultless letters and the paper is 100% white without a slightest texture. That means a 500 page book would need about half a gigabyte, which really isn't much. But that's only a theory. If the letters are printed they are everyone a little different. Thescanned page can easily take 20 megabytes and that jumps to 50MB if there's also paper texture.

Comment: (continued) 50 megabytes means 20 pages/gigabyte or 100 different 200 page books in a terabyte. Or 2 terabytes, if you have also one backup. Compression (JPEG, JPEG2000) would save space easily 80% and wrapping the scanned pages into a PDF utilizes them if one wants. Unfortunately nobody else, but you knows how much compression noise you would allow, how much storage you can invest and how good scans you can make. I suggest you to develop the scan or repro studio quality photographing process to the perfection at first. Know, that it's NOT trivial.

Comment: (cont'd) you wrote the time is not important. I'm afraid it's your most urgent problem. Use one minute to scan a page or a spread and to place it into an archive so that the quality is checked  and it can be found => You will do 60 scans/hour and that's fast. I wouldn't be able to work as fast a day without a substantial risk of unnoticed errors.

Comment: @user287001, isn't that an answer right there? I was planning to write something similar later. Tetsujin's remark about the troubles of getting the spreads flat without breaking the spine is also important to include.

Comment: Write an enhanced version which contains some hints from where to get  guidance for fast  and color accurate scanning or (I guess) preferably spread photographing with no reflections, light variations nor curved pages+ PDF making. If you repeat something of my writings - no problem. anyone who has hung around a while could write the same.

Comment: @user287001, haha yes - but it's growing and growing way beyond the initial question. Perhaps if the question were to be fleshed out a bit by the OP, I might consider writing an answer.

Comment: My wife works for a reprint house that scans books that are in the public domain. They usually scan at 600 ppi as PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution on the screen can be as low as 72 pixels per inch, but texts on the screen still are well readable and look sharp. That's because text on the screen are rendered from mathematically exactly defined vector shape fonts and they are sized and placed optimally to fit into the screen pixel matrix.

It would be a fatal error to think that 72 pixels per inch is high enough resolution to scan books. That's because the scanner cannot know the exact mathematical shapes of the scanned letters, so they cannot be positioned nor sized to fit optimally to the 72 ppi grid. I have found that a lower resolution than 300 ppi scan of say 11 pt text looks inferior on the screen. If one wants to reprint the 11 pt size text from an image of that text, the image should have at least 600 ppi. There's no exact inferior-sharp tresholds. The given numbers are only my opinions based only on my personal habits to see and decide what's sharp. You should make your own decision.

There's possible to make storage space estimations. I inserted some of them already in my comments. If it happens that you do not want any quality degrading compression and you want also paper color and texture or there's colored images you can well expect you need 50 megabytes per an A4 page. That's not much if you have a small library or endless pockets. But 100000 pages may be a reason to think to use some lossy compression to save space. Remember: You need also backups.

I have seen document scanners which output PDFs with JPEG or JPEG 2000 compression. You can well expect these compressions reduce the sizes of the files by 80% or even more.

It's up to you decide how much compression noise you allow to be inserted as the cost of storage space reduction.

Images in the books can generate a surprise which may need special attention book by book. Images are often made of discrete ink dots. Scanning or photographing such regular patterns can generate bad looking interference patterns when the image and the scanner happen to have too close pixel densities. The caused error is called "Moire" effect. One can fade it by changing the pixels per inch number used in scanning, but nothing removes it afterwards. More: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moiré_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)

As I wrote in my comment I guess the time will be your major problem. You need a fast way to make the scans (or take photographs of full spreads) and insert the take to the archive in a way which makes possible to check the result and find a certain page easily. In addition you surely expect consistent colors and uniform light with no glosses.

One of us lifted up problem "curved pages". The problem is common. Here in GDSE we have numerous of questions how to fix curved pages in images. People got them by photographing or scanning books which cannot be opened to straight. The only proper way is to avoid them beforehand.

A heavy glass plate doesn't help; many books get broken if one tries to force the opening to 180 degrees. In addition tricky polarization filtering is needed to kill the glosses.

One DIY photographing solution: Open the book only 90 degrees and take a photo of opposite pages simultaneously with 2 pro quality cameras which are aimed and adjusted manually beforehand. Everything must have sturdy mounts. A beforehand adjusted frame presses the page edges straight. There's no glosses if the light comes from a large distant surface and it's directed downwards. Bright light and small aperture keep the image sharp without re-focusing.

**My guidance**: Develop the scanning or photographing process so that the quality and total time/page needs are acceptable. If you use an ordinary home scanner and its utilities you may need work a minute per page or spread to get the image into your computer. Then there's the making of an usable PDF. Developing a practical way to build PDF books is another problem. Get some local help.

Comment: Ok, i can get a scanner that works on curved pages, or so they say.  To avoid large data needs, i can scan the five pages of each book, put those up on my eeb site, then if someone wants the whole book, i can charge them a modest fee to copy the whole thing!  I believe that 600 PPI, WOULD BE